Delphi executing an external program with two-way interaction
I need to execute a commandline program (.exe) in full interactive mode.
That is, I need to call the executable with a command which turns it into an interactive program. From the Windows command prompt (cmd) you can then communicate with the program.
I need to do the same from my own application.
I know I will have use 'CreateProcess' but I have not been able to find code which allows for two-way communication.
Update:
I have now tried this based on examples, but it hangs on PeekNamedPipe. The application then becomes unresponsive. I don't understand this because it should 'Peek'. What is wrong here?
    var
InputPipeRead,
OutputPipeRead,
ErrorPipeRead,
InputPipeWrite,
OutputPipeWrite,
ErrorPipeWrite: THandle;

procedure DoStart3;
    const
      CReadBuffer = 2400;
    var
      saSecurity: TSecurityAttributes;
      //hRead: THandle;
      //hWrite: THandle;
      suiStartup: TStartupInfo;
      piProcess: TProcessInformation;
      pBuffer: array[0..CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
      dRead: DWord;
      dRunning: DWord;
      dWritten: DWord;
      Command: String;
      BytesLeft: Integer;
      BytesAvail: Integer;
      ACount: integer;
    begin
      saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
      saSecurity.bInheritHandle := True;
      saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

      // if NOT CreatePipe(InputPipeRead, InputPipeWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then exit;
      if NOT CreatePipe(InputPipeRead, InputPipeWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then exit;
      if NOT CreatePipe(OutputPipeRead, OutputPipeWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then exit;
      if NOT CreatePipe(ErrorPipeRead, ErrorPipeWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then exit;

        FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
        suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
        suiStartup.hStdInput := InputPipeRead;
        suiStartup.hStdOutput := OutputPipeWrite;
        suiStartup.hStdError := ErrorPipeWrite;
        suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
        Command := 'C:\RMS Express\pat.exe interactive';
        UniqueString(Command);

        if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(Command), @saSecurity,@saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess) then
        begin
          Log('CreateProcess Start');
          ACount := 0;
          repeat
            dRunning  := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);
            Log('WaitForSingleObject done');
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            inc(ACount);
            repeat
              dRead := 0;
              Log('PeekNamedPipe...');
              if not PeekNamedPipe(InputPipeRead, @pbuffer, CReadBuffer, @dRead, @BytesAvail, @BytesLeft) then
              begin
                Log('PeekNamedPipe failed');
                RaiseLastOSError;
              end;
              Log('PeekNamedPipe done');
              if dRead <> 0 then
              begin
                Log('ReadFile');
                ReadFile(InputPipeRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, pBuffer);
                Log(string(pBuffer));
                // do something with the data
                // if a condition is present then do the following:
                // WriteFile(hWrite, some_command, size_of_buffer, DWritten, nil);
              end;
              sleep(1000);
              if ACount >= 30 then break;
            until (dRead < CReadBuffer);
            if ACount >= 15 then break;
          until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
          Log('CreateProcess Out of loop');
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
        end;
        CloseHandle(InputPipeRead);
        CloseHandle(OutputPipeWrite);
        CloseHandle(ErrorPipeWrite);
    end;


The first part of your question implies that the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag of CreateProcess() may be what you are looking for.  But then you mention two way communication, which implies you want to redirect stdin/out/err instead. Can you please clarify better what you are actually looking for?

Well. So the program I need to interact with is a "DOS" terminal program. When started with a special command from the command prompt, it keeps running, and from then it will listen to the keyboard, and replies via the screen. So, I would say this is indeed stdin/out. So I need to execute it, then communicate with it until I close it.

It's all about pipes - read How to send command to console application from GUI application and Pipes in Delphi for Command Prompt and How to read error running Console Application from Delphi Code using PeekNamedPipe().

If you want the user to interact with the launched app then CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE should suffice. If you want your launching app to interact with the launched app then you need to redirect its stdin/out/err with pipes.

You might have a look at DOSCommand, available from GetIt or GitHub: https://github.com/TurboPack/DOSCommand. The OnNewLine event gives you each console output line while the SendLine method allows to talk to the application.

I would have rather avoided a 3th party package for this, but yes, DOSCommand works perfectly in Delphy 12.1.  So That is what I will use now. Thanks.
